# Is the damage caused by a generic battery to a Lumix DMC-FZ20 likely permanent?

Tags: equipment-damage, battery, third-party

I just used a generic battery from eBay for my Lumix DMC-f20 and, worked for one session. After that, I downloaded to my computer, sans adapter, and, when I came back, the battery was depleted. I recharged and the camera turned on, then off. I recharged for a longer period and the battery chamber became extremely hot and the camera was just mute, or the camera equivalent, since then. I had misplaced my battery and charger, and didn't want to spend a lot for a temporary replacement. I'm really financially strapped at present.

Does anyone know if there's a chance the camera will work again with the OEM battery or ac adapter? I don't have the money to purchase an equivalent quality camera right now but need one to sell some items on eBay and Etsy?

If I had checked this site before purchasing one, I would never have done so, given what I've just read. Panasonic, especially, advises against this. I like others, gave the eBay seller positive feedback when the battery worked, for one session.

Thank you very much for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we do not know *what* died. If its the camera, it will need to be fixed which is *most likely*. Sorry to hear your lesson about saving on batteries was costly.

If you know a camera store with good service, go there and ask if they can try a replacement in your camera. If the camera does not turn on there, it is likely that it can be repaired but camera repair is notoriously expensive and worth it only for a camera of a certain value.